# Use high speed internet on hotspot

Tags: root-access, wifi-hotspot, 4g

Today I discovered that my cellphone provider, with the excuse of "saving my high speed quota" throttles the speed of my internet connection whenever I use hotspot.

For work reasons, I need a high speed connection on the go. If that uses my GBs, that is fine, I am paying for that.

The disappointing part is that for my provider to know that I am using hotspot, the operative system (Android) has to reveal that information to them, otherwise the provider has no way to know whether the connections started in the phone or some other device under it.

Is there a way to avoid this differentiation of connections' origin, so I could use a high speed connection in the hotspot? In other words, to make it look that all connections are coming from the phone?

Comment: @alecxs yes it does. my question is duplicated.